# Displaying Special Characters from MySQL Database in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to save text and then display text from MySQL Database in Joomla.

I created a PHP file to save text via post.

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO question(`question`) VALUE('$text')");
```

The text i copied from word had a special character.

The line copied was:

```
Total age = 20 × 9 = 180 years
```

In the database table (charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci), the text is saved as

```
Total age = 20 Ã— 9 = 180 years
```

Now if i fetch this text in a PHP and in that PHP i add this line:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Then the text is displayed correctly.

If i fetch the same text in a Joomla Website, which already has utf-8 meta (checked in source code), the text is not displayed correctly. It always shows:

```
Total age = 20 Ã— 9 = 180 years
```

I have tried adding these:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
utf8_encode($text);
```

But i could not decode the characters inside Joomla. Please help.

Comment: Its not topic but: why you use mysql_query? Joomla provide a own DB Class wich you are able to use: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase.

Comment: I am using mysql_query only on non Joomla pages. i have created a separate PHP file and trying to insert data with that and fetching the data inside Joomla

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Use utf8_general_ci as encoding for all your tables
- Use utf8_general_ci as encoding for your database

You can make these changes in phpMyAdmin (I think there is a query to change the character encoding for all the tables)

Comment: i changed the encoding (table and database) but still the text is not displayed correctly. i even deleted the table and created a new one with utf8_general_ci  encoding also but still no success. I think the problem is not how database is saving the text because i can easily display the text correctly outside Joomla. It must be some where in how Joomla encodes the text.